# How to access method/global variable from method linked with event listener?

Tags: javascript, html, methods, event-handling, es6-class

I can't access addComponaner()

```js
class Page{
    page = document.createElement('div');
    Componanet = [] ;

    constructor(page, Componanet){
        
        if (page == null) {} else {this.page = page;}
        if (Componanet == null) {} else {this.Componanet = Componanet; this.displayAll();}  
        this.page.id = 'page';
        this.page.addEventListener("click", this.listOfContent);
    }

    addComponanet(){
        
        this.Componanet.push(new Text(400,320));
    };

    listOfContent(){
        this.addComponanet();
        this.page.style.borderStylr = solid;
        this.page.style.display = "inline";
    }

}

class Text{
    text = document.createElement('div');
    constructor(xpos, ypos){
        this.text.style.top = xpos;
        this.text.style.left = ypos;
    }
}
```

/page variables now that I've coupled listOfContent with a click eventlistener.

Error message (Index.html:292 Uncaught TypeError: this.addComponanet is not a function at HTMLDivElement.listOfContent (Index.html:292:22) listOfContent @ Index.html:292)

Comment: I can't access addComponanet()/page variables now that I've coupled listOfContent with a click eventlistener.**

Comment: Just add arrow function like this "this.page.addEventListener("click", () => this.listOfContent());"

Answer (score 0):

Just change **normal function** to **arrow function** so that the value of `this` is the Page class, not `HTMLDivElement` when the event `click` is triggered.

```
listOfContent = () => {
    this.addComponanet();
    this.page.style.borderStylr = solid;
    this.page.style.display = "inline";
}
```